# How to use environment variable in sc create command?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a java process using below command

```
sc create JavaService binpath= "C:\\java-11-openjdk-11.0.15.9-1.windows.ojdkbuild.x86_64\\bin\\java.exe -jar C:\\data\\lib\\test-1.0.0.jar"
```

I have set env varibales Var1=Key1, Var2=Key2 on the system using set command. How do I pass Var1 or Var2 in above command.

I tried with -D option but that does not pick env variables.

```
sc create JavaService binpath= "C:\\java-11-openjdk-11.0.15.9-1.windows.ojdkbuild.x86_64\\bin\\java.exe -DVar1 -DVar2 -jar C:\\data\\lib\\test-1.0.0.jar"
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to run a non service executable with arguments as a Windows service, is that correct? And if so, why?

Comment: I echo @Compo's concern. Not sure if you can use java.exe in the first place but your format is incorrect. It's `-Dfoo=bar` normally

Comment: @g00se: both `-Dfoo` and `-Dfoo=bar` are valid; the former sets an empty string as the value. But both are for _system properties_ and have no relationship in any way to environment variables. In addition the env vars in a _service_ process are completely separate from the ones in a CMD process that runs the `sc` utility to create or otherwise manipulate the service.

Comment: @Compo, I want to run two services in a windows nanoserver container. One way to use supervisor-win utility, but nanoserver does not have dependencies built in for this. I think, creating separate services is more feasible for me at this moment.

Comment: I tried @g00se's solution, able to detect env vars, but service is restarting every ~30 seconds.

Comment: You will probably need a Java service wrapper